# Dwarf fortress crash Unexpectedly

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Months ago I tried to [Preventing climbers into fortress](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253125/preventing-climbers-into-fortress?rq=1) by building fort as shown in link. At start It felt that this is good idea. I started to construct fort. when I completed the work about halfway, DF crashed unexpectedly.

Now I am playing in new fortress. And thought I would try that method another time. But even this time that DF crashed.

I am playing DF 0.40.24-r3

So I want to ask Does this happen on only my pc? (In this case I will have to re download the game)

Or this is possibly a bug?

---

I am using lazy newb pack, with phoebus graphics pack, I am not using any utilities and with following custom settings

[image]

Comment: If you are using the lazy newb pack or some combination of other 3rd party utilities, they occasionally cause problems like crashing. I have, on my own PC, found that DF crashes regularly if I try to save a game without closing the dwarf therapist windows first. You might want to list any additions you have made to vanilla Dwarf fortress that you play with to help someone answer your question.

Comment: I am using lazy newb pack. with phoebus graphics. I will edit the question